# Should I use PHP's SQLSRV Functions?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am starting a new project in PHP that need to access MS Sql Server.
I know that PHP's manual lacks of warns about old or even deprecated set of functions.

- [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) extension do not refer to MySQLi extension at any point.
- [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) extension do not refer to SQLite3 extension at any point.

So my question is: Am I OK using PHP's [SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php) Functions? or they are not the state of the art?  I did choose them because aparently they have MS support.

Please notice that I am not asking for a recomendation, just if what I choose is OK

Comment: it looks like that's the way to go, as PDO does not support MS SQL server beyond PHP 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: are you going to be running this from a Windows machine?

Comment: just curious. Do you have requirements to access specific MS SQL  Server stuff that is not available via standard PDO queries? i.e. are your writing SQL Code that is specific to MS SQL Server only? May I ask for examples of SQL Code. that you use that are specific to MS SQL Server only, that you are required to use?

Comment: @RyanVincent What SQL Server *specific* means? Why would somebody use a product if they don't want to use that product's "special" features?

Comment: @Pred Lots of websites use database for dumb storage (sometimes even without keys :P) and use no product  specific feature but rather stick to what would be very portable SQL.

Comment: Always is to be considered *having into account your information schema* using PDO. As @acrosman said, there's PDO_SQLSRV available.

Comment: It must be Sql Server becouse I need to access a preexisting database shared with other apps

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it the [SQLSRV](http://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv) functions aren't actually PHP's per se since they are part of a package [maintained by Microsoft outside the main PHP project](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlsrv.php). They are however one of the two best bets for working with MS SQL Server ([PDO_SQLSRV](http://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv) being the other) since they are currently maintained.

They are both currently Windows only.